# Does SDL_SetWindowSize trigger a window event?

Tags: c++, c, sdl-2

In SDL2 when you resize the window by dragging the corners during runtime, a window resized event is triggered and can be used like this:

```
SDL_Event e;
int width, height;
SDL_PollEvent(&e);
if(e.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && e.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED)
{
    width = e.window.data1;
    height = e.window.data2;
}
```

If I resize a window manually like this:

```
SDL_SetWindowSize(window, myWidth, myHeight);
```

([documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowSize))
Will this trigger a window event like above?

Comment: It should be very easy to test, yes?

Comment: I'll test it and post the answer. But the post could be useful for someone else later.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yeah it should be easy to test, but to know if it does this on every platform or only some... you never really know with SDL. I can see why OP would be interested in what the docs / specs say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED, the answer is no. But an SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED event is triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just like `SDL_SetWindowFullscreen ()`. `SDL_SetWindowSize ()` triggers window events. Technically, I think it just resizes the window, which is treated as if the user manually resized it.

Comment: I was just about to post an answer myself. I tested this myself using SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED and SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED. SetWindowSize did not trigger an SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED event, but it did trigger an SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED event.

Comment: @larso I think it's standard practice to check for both. As long as you do that, whatever you are trying to achieve should work.